# What is "join" in MySQL without anything in front?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT ID, Name, Marks, Grade 
FROM Students AS s 
JOIN Grades AS g ON s.Marks BETWEEN g.Min_Mark AND g.Max_Mark;
```

I browsed numbers of resources about left join, right join, inner join and full outer join, but I have no idea what is this "join" means. Is this some shortcut? if not, what is this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you test it out? It's one of those you mentioned.

Comment: it is `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the [documentation from MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html). It says.

> In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.

To answer your question: join is the same like a inner join

Comment: I believe he asked what a join actually is.